# improve array of hashes performance while returning subset

Tags: ruby

1. 1.I am trying to get the subset of array of hashes which will reject duplicate names that are greater than >=3
2. for every 'number' key, return the subset of array of hashes with highest cost. If cost collides for that number return the first number (this number
   was converted off a timestamp to reflect 1..24 hours)

I was able to achieve the results with the following code:

```
a= [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>300},
    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>3, :cost=>400}]

a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.
  reject { |_, v| v.size >= 3 }.
  values.
  flatten.
  sort_by {|h| h[:number]}.group_by{|el| el[:number]}.
  values.
  map{|el| el.max_by{|x| x[:cost]}}

  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
```

Would the above result in O(n^2)

What would be a better approach?

Comment: For such a specific and complex problem, your code seems fairly concise. However, I do wonder: Why are you dealing with this messy array of hashes in the first place? You've tagged this as `ruby-on-rails`, which leads me to believe there may be e.g. a `Person` model with attributes including `name`, `number` and `cost`. Is this a problem that could actually be done with SQL, or even just by manipulating custom objects rather than `Hash`es? What was the *original* problem being solved?

Comment: No one has offered an answer because readers (like me, anyway) do not understand the question. Adding a small example that includes the desired return value would help explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The above example has the desired return value and is working fine. needed help in understanding the complexity of O(n^2)and see if it can improved to O(n)

Comment: Sorry, this is purely Ruby. I have removed the rails tag

Comment: You state, "for every 'number' key, return the name with highest cost", but in your example you return an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.
  each_value.
  reject { |v| v.size >= 3 }.
  flatten.
  group_by { |h| h[:number] }.
  transform_values { |v| v.max_by { |h| h[:cost] }[:name] }            
    #=> {1=>"John Doe3", 2=>"John Doe2"}
```

This return value seems consistent with what is being asked in the question. If the value of each number is to be the hash `h` for which `h[:cost]` is largest, simply remove `[:name]`:

```
  ...
  transform_values { |v| v.max_by { |h| h[:cost] } }            
    #=> {1=>{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    #    2=>{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}}
```

or, if desired:

```
  ...
  transform_values { |v| v.max_by { |h| h[:cost] } }.values            
    #=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
```

This has a computational complexity of O(n) (`n = a.size`) because each step requires a single pass through at most `a.size` elements.

The steps are as follows.

```
b = a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }
  #=> {"John Doe1"=>[
  #      {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #      {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #      {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #      {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>300},
  #      {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>3, :cost=>400}
  #    ],
  #    "John Doe3"=>[{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100}],
  #    "John Doe2"=>[{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
  #   }
```

We don't need the keys of this hash so we may as well extract the values now.

```
c = b.each_value
  #=> #<Enumerator: 
  #     {"John Doe1"=>[
  #        {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #        {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #        {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #        {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>300},
  #        {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>3, :cost=>400}
  #      ],
  #      "John Doe3"=>[{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100}],
  #      "John Doe2"=>[{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
  #     }:each_value>
```

Now remove the arrays containing 3 or more elements and flatten the result.

```
d = c.reject { |v| v.size >= 3 }
  #=> [
  #     [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100}],
  #     [{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]]

e = d.flatten
  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
```

We need to group the hashes once again, this time by the key `:number`.

```
f = e.group_by { |h| h[:number] }
  #=> {1=>[{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100}],
  #    2=>[{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]}
```

Lastly, for each value (array of hashes) of `f`select the element `h` for which `h[:cost]` is largest.

```
f.transform_values { |v| v.max_by { |h| h[:cost] } }
  # => {1=>{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
  #     2=>{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}}
```

Comment: @SimpleLime, good suggestion. I made the change. I should have caught that as using enumerators rather than arrays, where possible, is a hobby horse of mine. I can't count the times that I've suggested replacing `chars` with `each_char` in SO answers.

Comment: `{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>2, :cost=>400}` causes this to fail the desired output which appears to be the largest cost for each number where the name does not occur more than twice in the original array

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you for the counterexample. I see that I had misunderstood the question. I corrected my answer .

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that and made the correction. See my comment on the question. One more fix in progress related to the desired return value. There seems to be a conflict between the statement of what is desired and the OPs example.

Comment: sorry, updated the question, **subset of array of hashes

Comment: Edited. both solutions get the required result.+1 to both. Cary's solution is more readable for me.

Comment: @Micheal I assumed that given your concern over computational complexity that efficiency was the most important characteristic thus my answer but thank you for the kudos and best of luck

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be more efficient than your current solution: (by ~20% according to the `fruity` gem)

```
a.group_by {|h| h[:name] }.each_with_object({}) do |(_,v),obj|
  if v.size < 3 
    v.each do |sv| 
      if obj[sv[:number]].nil? || obj[sv[:number]][:cost] < sv[:cost]
        obj[sv[:number]] = sv
      end 
    end
  end
end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last) # or just end.values if the sort is not a requirement
#=> [{:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
#    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300}]
```

First we group by name.

Then we build a new `Hash` and for each group that has less than 3 members we rotate through the list and add the member to the `Hash` under its number if the number does not exist or the member's cost is greater than the current cost.

Then we sort by the keys (number) and output the values. If you do not need the sorting then you can just use `values`

**Benchmarking:** (provided by the [`fruity`](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem)
Since the original post included sorting but the accepted answer did not I benchmarked both options.

**Code**

```
def cary_swoveland(a)
  a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.
  each_value.
  reject { |v| v.size >= 3 }.
  flatten.
  group_by { |h| h[:number] }.
  transform_values { |v| v.max_by { |h| h[:cost] } }
end
def cary_swoveland_no_sort(a)
  cary_swoveland(a).values  
end
def cary_swoveland_sorted(a)
  cary_swoveland(a).sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)  
end
def engineers_mnky(a)
  a.group_by {|h| h[:name] }.each_with_object({}) do |(_,v),obj|
    if v.size < 3 
      v.each do |sv| 
        if obj[sv[:number]].nil? || obj[sv[:number]][:cost] < sv[:cost]
          obj[sv[:number]] = sv
        end 
      end
    end
  end
end
def engineers_mnky_no_sort(a)
  engineers_mnky.values
end
def engineers_mnky_sorted(a)
  engineers_mnky.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
end

def original_post_no_sort(a)
  a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.
  reject { |_, v| v.size >= 3 }.
  values.
  flatten.
  group_by{|el| el[:number]}.
  values.
  map{|el| el.max_by{|x| x[:cost]}}
end

def original_post(a)
  a.group_by { |el| el[:name] }.
  reject { |_, v| v.size >= 3 }.
  values.
  flatten.sort_by {|h| h[:number]}.
  group_by{|el| el[:number]}.
  values.
  map{|el| el.max_by{|x| x[:cost]}}
end
```

**Data**:

```
a= [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100},
    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>2, :cost=>400},
    {:name=>"John Doe3", :number=>1, :cost=>100}, 
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100}, 
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>100}, 
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>1, :cost=>300}, 
    {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>2, :cost=>300},
    {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>3, :cost=>400}]
```

**Results**:

```
# UNSORTED
Running each test 524288 times. Test will take about 4 minutes.
engineers_mnky_no_sort is faster than original_post_no_sort by 30.000000000000004% ± 1.0%
original_post_no_sort is faster than cary_swoveland_no_sort by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%

# SORTED 
Running each test 262144 times. Test will take about 3 minutes.
engineers_mnky_sorted is faster than original_post by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
original_post is faster than cary_swoveland_sorted by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
```

**Data**:

```
a = n.times.map do 
  {:name=>"John Doe#{rand(n / 2)}", :number=>(1..200).to_a.sample, :cost=>rand(1000)}
end
```

**Results**:

```
# Run 1 (n == 500)
# UNSORTED
Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 3 minutes.
engineers_mnky_no_sort is faster than original_post_no_sort by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
original_post_no_sort is similar to cary_swoveland_no_sort

# SORTED 
Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 4 minutes.
engineers_mnky_sorted is faster than cary_swoveland_sorted by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
cary_swoveland_sorted is similar to original_post

# Run 2 (n == 1_000)
# UNSORTED
Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 3 minutes.
engineers_mnky_no_sort is faster than original_post_no_sort by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
original_post_no_sort is similar to cary_swoveland_no_sort

# SORTED 
Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 4 minutes.
engineers_mnky_sorted is faster than cary_swoveland_sorted by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
cary_swoveland_sorted is faster than original_post by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
```

Comment: Could you fruitify my solution as well?

Comment: @CarySwoveland fruity benchmarks posted (RUBY_VERSION 2.5.1)

Comment: @engineersmnky. what does this do: .sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)

Comment: @Micheal `sort_by` will convert the key/value pairs to an `Array` such that the argument looks like `[key, value]` so we are sorting by the key (first) which is `number` in this case then map the `values` (last).